# django url pattern strips forward slash when running in nginx+uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx

For the following url pattern:

```
re_path(r'proxy/(?P<url>.*)', myview)
```

When I send `proxy/http://www.google.com`

myview function receives url as `http:/www.google.com` (with single `/`)

It happens with uwsgi+nginx setup , when running with runserver url is `http://www.google.com` .

Comment: I think you should send this url value as url querystring

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-proxy where it handles other requests parameters .. to forward requests to the specified url... and I think there is a way to handle this , otherwise the library is severely flawed

Comment: I just saw the library docs, it did not show any indication of passing Protocol and host information though url argument.

Comment: url('proxy/(?P<url>.*)', proxy_view), and the view function gives url to requests lib, and requests expect protocol to be there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `nginx` will automatically merge double slashes in URLs into a single one:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

> Enables or disables compression of two or more adjacent slashes in a URI into a single slash.
>
> Note that compression is essential for the correct matching of prefix string and regular expression locations. Without it, the “//scripts/one.php” request would not match

You should disable it in your `nginx.conf`:

```
merge_slashes off;
```

Comment: yes!, It fixed it.. you have to put it in `server` context